# ansible tower_role module - no field named tower_verify_ssl

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

Trying out the Ansible tower_role module, and I can't seem to get past this error:

> The Tower server claims it was sent a bad request.\n\nGET
>   https://myansibletowerserver/api/v2/projects/123/object_roles/\nParams:
>   {'role_field': 'admin_role', 'tower_verify_ssl': True}\nData:
>   None\n\nResponse: {\"detail\":\"Role has no field named
>   'tower_verify_ssl'

Sample usage/scenario was using the role module to apply permissions to a project:

```
- name: Update team to be admin for named project
  tower_role:
    project: "{{ short_appname }}-playbook"
    team: "CORP DEVELOPER"
    role: admin
    state: present
    tower_config_file: "{{ tower_config }}"
```

Ansible 2.7.1

tower-cli 3.3.0

target Ansible Tower server: 3.2.3

TIA!